# How can I convert Statistics Canada from SHP/GML/MAP to JSON?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to do a choropleth on leaflet with data from Statistics Canada. For some reason, I just can't convert the data from this page: https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2016-eng.cfm

I've tried many ways and failed. The closest I went to reach my goal was with mapshaper, but for some reason I didn't get any latitude/longitude data (46.xxxxx, -75.xxxxx) but positive numbers like 80.xxxxx, 45.xxxx.

How should I proceeed?

Thanks

P.S. I tried GDAL but couldn't find any .exe file to launch the software after download and didn't understand how it works.

P.S.1. Here is some data I got... Don't understand how to use the data. It doesn't look like latitude/longitude at all...

```
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4430789.257144999,2586893.2714300007],[4431394.088569999,2586921.9685700014],[4431518.514284998,2586927.8885699995],[4431559.800000001,2586929.8542850018],[4431835.059999999,2586942.9514300004],[4431902.997145001,2586946.185715001],[4431956.248569999,2586948.719999999],[4432181.440000001,2586960.148570001],[4432128.4428550005,2586865.5199999996],[4431235.722855002,2585271.4542849995],[4431224.805714998,2585248.0714300014],[4431139.31143,2585064.97143],[4431126.077144999,2585036.6257149987],[4431113.082855001,2585041.462855],[4431099.960000001,2585046.3485700004],[4431043.482855,2585058.5571449995],[4431041.705715001,2585058.182854999],[4430982.808570001,2585045.725715],[4430837.440000001,2584980.262855001],[4430824.97143,2584974.6457149982],[4430780.539999999,2584963.0714300014],[4430736.842854999,2584951.685715001],[4430680.731430002,2584947.1799999997],[4430511.717145,2584953.4657149985],[4430414.174284998,2584931.6999999993],[4430378.485715002,2584923.737144999],[4430294.1000000015,2584920.657145001],[4430239.185715001,2584930.5085700005],[4430155.577144999,2584975.594285],[4430054.191429999,2585030.3599999994],[4429933.685715001,2585066.622855],[4429921.86857,2585066.514284998],[4429666.431430001,2585064.182854999],[4429575.760000002,2585095.2714300007],[4429442.445714999,2585221.5857149996],[4429343.168570001,2585261.280000001],[4429301.68,2585277.86857],[4429261.420000002,2585283.445714999],[4429121.1114300005,2585276.3228549995],[4428957.585715,2585294.3542850018],[4428828.705715001,2585321.13143],[4428751.162854999,2585352.4657149985],[4428750.277144998,2585352.8228549995],[4428718.054285001,2585365.845715001],[4428637.305714998,2585363.6771450005],[4428622.734285001,2585363.2885700017],[4428553.365715001,2585313.81143],[4428546.794284999,2585309.1257149987],[4428514.47143,2585219.460000001],[4428492.162854999,2585182.8885699995],[4428453.15143,2585157.037145],[4428411.182854999,2585162.351429999],[4428359.0085700005,2585183.6428549998],[4428334.168570001,2585201.4371449985],[4428262.808570001,2585252.5599999987],[4428225.185715001,2585268.4771450013],[4428213.52857,2585268.960000001],[4428170.577144999,2585270.7342850007],[4428117.485715002,2585261.405715],[4428081.605714999,2585241.280000001],[4428041.47143,2585200.622855],[4428023.911430001,2585182.8371450007],[4428022.371429998,2585181.274285],[4427887.0085700005,2584943.9285699986],[4427726.805714998,2584804.6657150015],[4427605.1000000015,2584734.63143],[4427576.18857,2584717.9942849986],[4427446.197145,2584627.502854999],[4427298.408569999,2584555.2457149997],[4427225.285714999,2584533.7971450016],[4427129.462855,2584525.5885699987],[4427124.137145001,2584527.905715],[4427100.1657150015,2584538.342854999],[4426983.777144998,2584638.9428550005],[4426972.920000002,2584647.6514299996],[4426961.9542849995,2584656.445714999],[4426754.628570002,2584800.9142850004],[4426731.865715001,2584816.774285],[4426639.82,2584910.445714999],[4426580.5,2584934.917144999],[4426549.054285001,2584928.948569998],[4426535.897144999,2584922.7542850003],[4426509.608569998,2584831.748569999],[4426510.108569998,2584790.6742849983],[4426511.962855,2584638.8228549995],[4426506.719999999,2584571.1400000006],[4426493.300000001,2584526.3914300017],[4426454.648570001,2584469.714285001],[4426407.805714998,2584442.8485700004],[4426403.394285001,2584440.3200000003],[4426378.148570001,2584444.582855001],[4426294.822854999,2584493.9657149985],[4426228.277144998,2584584.120000001],[4426193.805714998,2584596.0571449995],[4426158.982855,2584608.1142849997],[4426145.828570001,2584605.1657150015],[4426132.539999999,2584602.18857],[4426102.337145001,2584551.8542850018],[4426092.905715,2584481.3999999985],[4426135.642855,2584364.1371450014],[4426151.374285001,2584320.97143],[4426158.448569998,2584254.1685700007],[4426134.18,2584199.6142849997],[4426079.505715001,2584135.405715],[4425995.628570002,2584106.511429999],[4425910.905715,2584077.3228549995],[4425781.802855,2584060.0599999987],[4425770.45143,2584058.539999999],[4425751.785714999,2584046.8200000003],[4425703.817145001,2584016.6999999993],[4425668.725715,2583994.6657150015],[4425657.177145001,2583982.7828550003],[4425618.154284999,2583942.6400000006],[4425567.071430001,2583890.0885699987],[4425540.722855002,2583868.4028550014],[4425528.0571449995,2583857.9800000004],[4425514.108569998,2583846.5],[4425483.277144998,2583828.448569998],[4425482.414285,2583827.9428550005],[4425424.588569999,2583794.0885699987],[4424859.254285,2584450.20857],[4424750.0085700005,2584630.317145001],[4424629.120000001,2584932.4828549996],[4424596.391430002,2585249.5571449995],[4424546.914285,2585230.8714299984],[4424562.125714999,2585263.6999999993],[4424567.997145001,2585276.36857],[4424602.577144999,2585350.997145001],[4424659.34857,2585473.1028550006],[4424707.691429999,2585575.714285001],[4424767.5457150005,2585702.7657149993],[4424815.702854998,2585787.4542849995],[4424877.174284998,2585866.5057150014],[4424933.671429999,2585925.0199999996],[4424993.325715002,2585975.922855001],[4425020.497145001,2585996.16],[4425072.194285002,2586034.6657150015],[4425163.960000001,2586103.014284998],[4425205.785714999,2586134.1685700007],[4425318.294284999,2586217.9685700014],[4425538.737144999,2586382.1628549993],[4425571.117144998,2586403.094285],[4425596.094285,2586419.2428550012],[4425716.405715,2586482.7457149997],[4425885.928569999,2586553.1257149987],[4426088.460000001,2586635.537145],[4426304.728569999,2586724.511429999],[4426387.877145,2586758.3057149984],[4426473.531429999,2586793.117144998],[4426486.31143,2586798.31143],[4426489.04857,2586799.422855001],[4426494.68,2586801.7114299983],[4426641.042854998,2586861.197145],[4426937.559999999,2586981.654284999],[4427057.84,2587027.634284999],[4427189.305714998,2587061.6371450014],[4427292.337145001,2587078.780000001],[4427681.614285,2587092.4257149994],[4427687.828570001,2587092.1771450005],[4428045.448569998,2587077.9514300004],[4428085.280000001,2587076.36857],[4428347.585715,2587065.9371449985],[4428391.420000002,2587064.1942850016],[4428547.757144999,2587047.905715],[4428973.428569999,2587003.5599999987],[4429331.29143,2586965.9914299995],[4429416.15143,2586957.082855001],[4429560.537145,2586941.9257149994],[4429640.15143,2586933.5714300014],[4430146.242855001,2586880.4514300004],[4430256.982855,2586872.697145],[4430474.82,2586878.3542850018],[4430616.199999999,2586885.0628550015],[4430789.257144999,2586893.2714300007]]]},"properties":{"ADIDU":"59550131","PRIDU":"59","PRNOM":"British Columbia / Colombie-Britannique","DRIDU":"5955","DRNOM":"Peace River","DRGENRE":"RD","SRUIDU":"5955023","SRUNOM":"Peace River E","SDRIDU":"5955023","SDRNOM":"Peace River E","SDRGENRE":"RDA","RÉIDU":"5980","RÉNOM":"Northeast / Nord-est","CSSCODE":"997","CSSGENRE":"5","RMRIDU":"","RMRPIDU":"","RMRNOM":"","RMRGENRE":"","SRIDU":"","SRNOM":"","ADAIDU":"59550004"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[4434380.18,2584958.6914299987],[4434198.559999999,2584518.0599999987],[4433504.168570001,2584830.537145],[4433665.617144998,2585139.157145001],[4433345.037145,2585299.3314299993],[4433289.780000001,2585389.7285699993],[4433205.268569998,2585453.1657150015],[4433066.468570001,2585557.3485700004],[4433028.65143,2585471.117144998],[4432985.671429999,2585373.1085699983],[4432881.705715001,2585070.3200000003],[4432024.308570001,2585503.605714999],[4432018.0457150005,2585506.31143],[4432000.928569999,2585561.945714999],[4431943.66,2585581.3257150017],[4431909.371429998,2585581.785714999],[4431870.342854999,2585598.0342850015],[4431826.800000001,2585588.8857150003],[4431799.382855002,2585581.351429999],[4431794.302855,2585569.6457149982],[4431799.294284999,2585558.068569999],[4431854.408569999,2585536.6457149982],[4431856.308570001,2585521.2428550012],[4431845.734285001,2585505.7057150006],[4431816.20857,2585514.7171449997],[4431789.277144998,2585510.051430002],[4431773.9428550005,2585489.4428550005],[4431722.205715001,2585485.8314299993],[4431714.865715001,2585471.97143],[4431718.420000002,2585439.025715001],[4431710.102855001,2585425.6457149982],[4431642.34857,2585415.0057150014],[4431633.685715001,2585400.7657149993],[4431633.725715,2585399.774285],[4431635.077144999,2585367.8628549986],[4431627.082855001,2585361.1142849997],[4431599.262855001,2585367.002854999],[4431588.031429999,2585360.6685700007],[4431550.5,2585308.4657149985],[4431529.597144999,2585317.2971450016],[4431510.8885699995,2585338.417144999],[4431505.36857,2585382.2771449983],[4431482.920000002,2585415.8857150003],[4431457.108569998,2585454.5314299986],[4431448.842854999,2585455.582855001],[4431436.385715,2585434.3857150003],[4431428.95143,2585395.154284999],[4431434.088569999,2585356.877145],[4431425.422855001,2585342.634284999],[4431398.817145001,2585344.6000000015],[4431378.774285,2585388.497145001],[4431362.154284999,2585405.0885699987],[4431333.071430001,2585398.3857150003],[4431332.817145001,2585397.7542850003],[4431361.705715001,2584923.328570001],[4431369.391430002,2584797.091430001],[4431365.81143,2584802.817145001],[4431338.217145,2584837.685715001],[4431253.317145001,2584944.9657149985],[4431194.851429999,2584997.5428549983],[4431186.114285,2585005.3999999985],[4431171.8342849985,2585012.828570001],[4431126.077144999,2585036.6257149987],[4431139.31143,2585064.97143],[4431224.805714998,2585248.0714300014],[4431235.722855002,2585271.4542849995],[4432128.4428550005,2586865.5199999996],[4432181.440000001,2586960.148570001],[4432305.068569999,2586968.1799999997],[4432800.374285001,2587016.622855],[4432956.871429998,2587032.448569998],[4432985.4542849995,2587035.34],[4433004.914285,2587037.0885699987],[4433017.225715,2587040.6257149987],[4433058.0571449995,2587040.9685700014],[4433109.694285002,2587033.737144999],[4433157.394285001,2587019.9800000004],[4433180.562855002,2587009.02857],[4433184.52857,2587007.157145001],[4433187.605714999,2587005.7028549984],[4433226.788570002,2586985.9514300004],[4433261.628570002,2586959.5571449995],[4433314.011429999,2586913.9800000004],[4433319.117144998,2586905.2171449997],[4433378.357145,2586854.8228549995],[4433419.282855,2586819.814284999],[4433432.1657150015,2586808.7942849994],[4433689.391430002,2586588.7571449988],[4433708.591430001,2586568.6942850016],[4433752.885715,2586517.654284999],[4433788.237144999,2586462.2228550017],[4433892.879999999,2586279.551430002],[4433950.32,2586181.9942849986],[4433992.754285,2586112.237144999],[4434034.194285002,2586061.9542849995],[4434082.042854998,2586012.905715],[4434145.668570001,2585962.2228550017],[4434171.379999999,2585941.814284999],[4434191.837145001,2585925.577144999],[4434212.371429998,2585909.2771449983],[4434228.559999999,2585896.4285699986],[4434256.702854998,2585874.0885699987],[4434271.657145001,2585862.219999999],[4434281.760000002,2585854.1999999993],[4434315.322854999,2585818.2600000016],[4434345.485715002,2585770.280000001],[4434349.085715,2585761.3542850018],[4434366.265714999,2585718.7342850007],[4434372.645714998,2585685.9142850004],[4434375.314284999,2585650.345715001],[4434376.911430001,2585629.0971449986],[4434365.122855,2585563.317145001],[4434355.95143,2585513.6742849983],[4434313.857145,2585279.997145001],[4434312.037145,2585244.845715001],[4434314.731430002,2585187.2228550017],[4434315.625714999,2585168.0314299986],[4434326.828570001,2585093.908569999],[4434336.04857,2585064.671429999],[4434349.808570001,2585021.037145],[4434368.15143,2584981.274285],[4434374.120000001,2584968.3342849985],[4434380.18,2584958.6914299987]]]},"properties":{"ADIDU":"59550132","PRIDU":"59","PRNOM":"British Columbia / Colombie-Britannique","DRIDU":"5955","DRNOM":"Peace River","DRGENRE":"RD","SRUIDU":"5955023","SRUNOM":"Peace River E","SDRIDU":"5955010","SDRNOM":"Chetwynd","SDRGENRE":"DM","RÉIDU":"5980","RÉNOM":"Northeast / Nord-est","CSSCODE":"998","CSSGENRE":"6","RMRIDU":"","RMRPIDU":"","RMRNOM":"","RMRGENRE":"","SRIDU":"","SRNOM":"","ADAIDU":"59550004"}},
```

Comment: The data in PS1 is Geojson. But the data from the link is not. Do you want to overlay both?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still a newbie and not sure what is the difference between JSON and GEOJSON, but what I did was convert SHP to one or the other. What I want to do is to use Statistics Canada dissemination area overlayed on a mapbox map to do a choropleth. 

I did see an example of such a thing in the US by states, but coordinates were actual longitude/latitude coordinates; I don't understand why Statistics Canada coordinates are all positive.

How can I convert data from the link and how can I overlay the dissemination area on a mapbox map?

Thank you very much!